# What to do with "programming" Qs that are actually just basic arithmetic/ratio questions?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, low-quality-posts, canonical

There's a category of questions that are **only titularly "programming"** and are in fact just simple ratio or pre-algebra questions, example:

[Transform rotation based on the "Minutes" (Unity 3D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35402211/transform-rotation-based-on-the-minutes-unity-3d)

...these have nothing to do with the Unity3D tag, or really any particular programming language.

Of course, it's inconceivable it could be a **duplicate *per se*** (unless someone coincidentally wanted to know about the same number of bananas or seconds).

What's the best close-reason for this sort of thing, or, is there any other course of action?

Is there perhaps some **canonical answer somewhere** which says *"Such problems are solved by applying prealgebra. Here's a summary of that: blah blah. Use the relevant programming language to achieve the four arithmetic operations. If you have a specific prealgebra problem, ask on a math QA site."* ... or something like that?

Note that similarly, when someone asks an advanced question about physics, per se, for use in games, they are just sensibly directed to the physics site.

These "actually just prealgebra" questions come up all the time, what to do.

(indeed as math questions, I believe they are just too simple to mover along to math.se - I don't think those dudes take questions like "if I'm going 20 kph how far in 30 minutes" ...)

Comment: Would it be something that could be added to the tag wiki of Unity3d?

Comment: There is this little button on the left side of the question that you could use to downvote it

Comment: I .. do't really know, I more leave it to you experts.  But simply (A) I don't know what to click to close it and (B) if there's some warning or something you can add to help reduce the incredible clutter in Unity3D - great

Comment: If the posters are on a 'one account per question' strategy, a downvote is a vote wasted:(

Comment: hi @Kevin - that's pretty silly dude.  Even I know downvoting is completely different from "needing to be closed and deleted from the site". The two issues are not related.

Comment: I know they're not, but if the question doesn't fit any of the close reasons, it probably isn't off topic for the site, and instead is just very low quality. hence, downvote so that it will be deleted.

Comment: okie dokey ... so wait you're saying questions are deleted if they get downvotes?  How many?

Comment: a negatively scored question with no positively scored answers gets automatically deleted after a period of time (period of time is based on circumstances ranging from 1 month to 1 year)

Comment: hi Kevin - I didn't know that. unfortunately that doesn't work - there's always some joker that types out an answer to such questions.  But really, closing is closing - they need to be closed now. You know?  Anyways Serv has answerethed.

Comment: This question has utterly nothing to do with that "awful" questions question.  I'm asking about the **specific very common case** of people asking "programming" questions that are actually just simple prealgebra question. (They're not particularly horrible or "awful" questions, but they are arguably just math rather than programming per se.)  (As you can see by reading the excellent answers here.)  Can you remove the close thingy - well, whatever, not something I have time for.  @gnat

Comment: anyways no worries, thanks for the answers men!

Comment: I have to agree with Joe Blow; @gnat how is the question "please advise me on how best to deal with questions about arithmetic and simple applications of formulae" even close to being the same as the feature request "give me the power to close bad questions of all types without offering any commentary explaining what was wrong with them"? They're wildly different to each other.

Comment: Hey @MarkAmery, i tightened up the question a little, anyways. cheers all

Comment: There's a similar category of question, the `my if/else doesn't work` question - where the problem is not that the asker does not know how to program (they don't), but that the asker has no idea how to use the actual logical concepts of if and else.

Comment: FWIW, we _do_ occasionally get questions about ratios and other such simple arithmetic on SE.mathematics, and if the OP explains the problem clearly and shows what they've tried then the question will be treated just like any other well-asked question. However, IMHO, someone who doesn't understand basic arithmetic may not have the aptitude to become a competent programmer.

Comment: This problem is very common in R questions, asking for statistical things instead programming ones.

Comment: hi @durum.  it makes me think (A) perhaps a good close reason would be, and this seems pretty clear, ***THIS QUESTION IS NOT ACTUALLY ABOUT PROGRAMMING***.  Does anyone know, has this already been suggested or whatever?

Comment: @Joe You mean like the "Off-topic" close reason?

Comment: @JoeBlow For the first few years of the site we had that, almost to the word ("This question is not programming-related"), but it went away shortly after SuperUser launched and migrations became a thing, and we've been left with inferior substitutes ever since :)

Comment: @Michael you need to write a custom reason for that, these days, and instead of working up the ambition, I just leave the page.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If it's clear that they don't know what they need to make the programming language do, then use a custom close reason to explain that the problem is an arithmetic problem, rather than a programming problem. If they've made it clear that they understand the mathematic operations that should be performed, but don't know how to make the programming language perform those operations, then the question wouldn't be off topic (but that probably *would* have a clear duplicate, and would also *probably* be poorly researched, as this information tends to be readily accessible).

Comment: dude I fear there is not a "poorly researched" close reason?? (correct me if wrong, thanks)

Comment: @JoeBlow Don't use "doesn't understand algebra" as a close reason.  Use, "this question is about algebra, rather than programming" as a close reason.  As to there not being a duplicate in the latter case, I'd hope that there wouldn't be, but I would expect that there probably would be.  I certainly agree that it would be an awful question, but it wouldn't merit closure, just downvoting, as far as I can see.

Comment: @JoeBlow "dude I fear there is not a "poorly researched" close reason?? (correct me if wrong, thanks)" You are unfortunately correct.

Comment: got it both times THANKS  "this question is about algebra, rather than programming" yeah great thinking, obvious once you say it, cheers

Answer (score 16):

> Is there perhaps some canonical answer somewhere which says "Such problems are solved by applying grade-school prealgebra. Here's a summary of that: blah blah..."

There may or may not be, but any given well-written question is an opportunity to make one. You can cover the problem at large while, if you so desire, plugging in the specific numbers the OP has given, simply to produce a working example.

Once you have a clear and helpful answer explaining the general solution, you can use the question as a duplicate master for any other instances that pop up that differ only in the particular values of *x* and *y*. Duplicate closure definitely covers two questions with the same operation on sightly different input.

Personally, I don't in general take issue with mathematical/algebraic questions that have come up in the course of coding. I think the category of math problems that people run into (especially for games/graphics) and the need to express the problem in code make them perfectly suitable to ask other programmers rather than mathematicians. Take a look at these two, as food for thought:

- [Math question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/466198/algorithm-to-get-the-maximum-size-of-n-squares-that-fit-into-a-rectangle-with-a?rq=1)
- [Code question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575589/resizing-n-of-squares-to-be-as-big-as-possible-while-still-fitting-into-box-of)

But I understand if others do think they're a bad fit. If you really don't think the question is a good addition to the site, then by all means vote to close as off-topic, [as Servy has recommended](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/316915/603977).

Comment: Fair enough.  I think it would take a lot of moral fortitude to sit down and answer such a question - beyond me!  :)  You know, the two links you mention are to at least somewhat non-trivial question (funnily enough I recently provided a long canonical-like answer re space filling for basic games use .. http://stackoverflow.com/a/35228592/294884) ... it's perhaps worth considering, the question I ask about here is on the level "so how many oranges did Jane get?!" you know.  Anyways.  Good one.

Answer (score 9):

If the OP seems so clueless that they do not understand basic arithmetic, algebra or logic, and does not understand that their question is actually about those subjects rather than programming, any explanation *that they could understand* would amount to a tutorial about arithmetic, algebra or logic and the difference between those subjects and programming. Such an answer would be some mixture of *too broad* and *off topic*. So such questions can be closed using the existing close reasons.

Comment: It just makes me think that SO is screaming out for a close reason along the lines: "this is not really a question as such, rather it would require an extremely basic tutorial in programming or arithmetic."

Comment: indeed if you simply click to "unity3D" tag at the moment, say 2/3 of the questions in the queue are impossibly basic. for example there's this category of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454064/unity-check-if-an-object-collided-at-a-position which is simply saying "what is a collider".  ..I mean its ontologically confusing .. the OP is asking "how do I check collisions" .. answer ... "uh .. colliders" it's kind of one step beyond "just google it". the answer here is "you actually wrote the answer - 'colliders' - when you wrote the question. Be reassured! You're right!"  :)

Comment: i guess as you say *too broad* is the solution for that

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 very different languages.

One is "mathematics" where all operators are instant, nothing ever overflows, there is never any loss of precision, etc.

One is "programming" where things like cache misses and RAM consumption, data formats, APIs, etc are all important.

These languages are very different and incomparable. If you don't believe me, see how much a mathematician likes `x = x + 1`.

Someone can be very fluent in one language and unskilled in another. I am a little like this myself. For complex subjects, I can stare at "alien mathematical gibberish" for hours, and see some example code and understand within 5 minutes.

If someone asks (e.g.) "How do I find a rotation matrix from forward and up vectors in C#" (where the answer may be "Use this API function") and you give them the answer for "How do I find a rotation matrix from forward and up vectors in mathematics"; then it's no different to someone asking "How do I describe the life cycle of frogs in English" and someone providing an answer for Spanish.

Don't blame the person asking the question. Blame the person trying to provide a wrong answer for the wrong language.